# Vimeo PHP API - Make Authenticated Request

Tags: php, json, api

I'm using the Vimeo API here:
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

I've included it like this:

```
 // include the autoload file from the vimeo php library that was downloaded
include __DIR__ . '/vimeo/autoload.php';

// The client id and client secret needed to use the vimeo API
$clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

// when getting an auth token we need to provide the scope
// all possible scopes can be found here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#supported-scopes
$scope = array('public', 'private');

// initialize the vimeo library
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);

// request an auth token (needed for all requests to the Vimeo API)
$token = $lib->clientCredentials($scope);

// redirect_uri must be provided, and must match your configured uri
$token = $lib->accessToken(code, redirect_uri);

// use the token
$lib->setToken($token['body']['access_token']);
```

Then I try to get the video thumb url:

```
$vimeo_response = $lib->request('/videos/218234161/pictures', 'GET');
```

This just returns a null value.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: The two parameters of the `accessToken` method are constants?

Comment: I got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it working by generating an access token here:
https://developer.vimeo.com/apps

Once I had the token along with client id and secret, this was is code:

```
    // include the autoload file from the vimeo php library that was 
    include __DIR__ . '/vimeo/autoload.php';
    use Vimeo\Vimeo;

    function get_vimeo_thumb($vimeo_video_id){

    // The client id and client secret needed to use the vimeo API
    $clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    //// initialize the vimeo library
    $vimeo = new Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);

    // Set access token
    $vimeo->setToken($access_token);

    $thumb = $vimeo->request("/videos/" . $vimeo_video_id . "/pictures/");
    return $thumb['body']['data'][0]['sizes'][2]['link'];

   }
```